# Google map - get lake names from XML data?

Tags: google-maps

I have a database of Google markers that I need to get lake/body of water names from.  Does anybody know of a service that can do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a webservice such as http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearby or Yahoo Place finder http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/ . Google reverse geocoder does not seem to be doing the best job with places of interests (such as lakes or rivers).